# Routing ASP.NET MVC URL to url with querystring

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have to map a nice looking ASP.NET MVC URL '/sel/F/61' to an ASPX url with query string parameters like 'familydrilldown.aspx?familyid=61'. I tried to add this to global.asax:

```
routeTable.MapPageRoute(
                "selectorroute", 
                "sel/F/{familyid}", 
                "~/selector/familydrilldown.aspx");
```

which works, except that the familyid is not passed as a querystring to familydrilldown.aspx.

How can I take the {familyid} and pass it as a querystring parameter to the page familydrilldown.aspx?

I tried this:

```
routeTable.MapPageRoute(
                "selectorroute", 
                "sel/F/{familyid}", 
                "~/selector/familydrilldown.aspx?familyid={familyid}");
```

but of course this doesn't really work...

Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: I ran into exactly the same issue. It sure would be nice if the syntax you used above actually worked! As is, I've got a lot of code that looks first for a query string, then for route data. Maybe I'll work on a generic version of Lud's solution if I get bored some day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution by implementing my own IRouteHandler:

```
public class SelectorRouteHandler<T> : IRouteHandler 
    where T : IHttpHandler, new()
{                                      
    public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        string queryString = 
            "?familyid=" + requestContext.RouteData.Values["familyid"];

        HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(
            string.Concat("~/selector/familydrilldown.aspx", queryString));

        var page = BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(
            "~/selector/familydrilldown.aspx", typeof(T)) as IHttpHandler;

        return page;                    
    }
}
```

and registering it like:

```
routeTable.Add(
    "selectorRoute", 
    new Route("sel/F/{familyid}", SelectorRouteHandler<Page>()));
```

Comment: +1, but just a note, you can also get at the `HttpContext` object via `requestContext.HttpContext`. I imagine that the two implementations are roughly equivalent, but to me, it feels better to use the `requestContext` object.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if what you want is possible.
Why don't you just use?

```
var familyId = Page.RouteData.Values["familyid"]
```

in the Page_Load (there might be some casting involved)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The aspx pages already exist, so it would be nice if we don't need to change them... and currently they use the Request.QueryString object...