# How to achieve url writing in Asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, url

I am creating a webforms asp.net application

I want a specific url for each user according to there username.

Something like `www.mywebsite.com/agent/username`  this will load `www.mywebsite.com/agent/default.aspx`

Username correspond to that agent

Is it possible ?

Thanks

Comment: What version of asp.Net are we talking about?

Comment: You can use a urlrewrite module (plenty of them to choose from) that would load `www.mywebsite.com/agent/default.aspx?username={0}` where `{0}` is the `username` for example.  Or use something like MVC that comes built with URL rewriting at its core.

Comment: @EliGassert ya correct but i am using .net 4.0 web form application so cant use MVC...any other suggestion?

Comment: Yes, do the first thing I suggested :) http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Comment: You could use an [HTTP handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986(v=vs.100).aspx) for that.

Comment: i am not getting how to use these? any tutorial will be appreciated - Thanks

Comment: @Nishantverma - [How to: Use Routing with Web Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668202(v=VS.90).aspx)... not sure if latest version need even less code to do that... zimdanen's answer (+1) have better link.

Answer (score 5):

You can use ASP.NET Routing without using MVC.  Take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Basically just define route that points to ASPX page - see sample in the article/related HowTo. Snippet below:

```
void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
  routes.MapPageRoute("",
      "SalesReport/{locale}/{year}/{*queryvalues}", "~/sales.aspx");
```

Comment: in which page i should register it? www.mywebsite.com/agent/default.aspx ??

Comment: @Nishantverma: If you take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668177(v=vs.100).aspx), you'll have more details, but you basically want to define it in your Global.asax.

Comment: yup got it let me try once

Comment: i just changed code void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.MapPageRoute("Default", "agent/{*queryvalues}", "~/agent/default.aspx");
        } code

Comment: now how to read the username in the default.aspx page?

Comment: @Nishantverma:  You'll want to add a query string on the end that has the queryValues.

Comment: i am not getting can u give me syntax example ?

Comment: @Nishantverma:  You could either [implement your own route handler](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6108461/128217), or you could just [get the route data](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6100268/128217) in the page.